# mPdf Output with include not working

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm using mdpf to output the php file to a pdf file. The problem is that I have an include it doesn't output the file at all. When I takeout the include it works, however, when I put it back in, it just goes straight to the browser.

Here is the code:

```
  <?php
      session_start();
      require('mpdf.php');
      $mpdf=new mPDF();

      ob_start();

      $id   =  $_POST['tempId'];
      $_SESSION = $id

      include('report-gen.php');

      $html = ob_get_contents();

      ob_end_clean();

      $mpdf = new mPDF();
      $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
      $mpdf->debug = true;
      $fileName = $id.'.pdf';
      //$mpdf->SetProtection(array(), 'user', 'password'); uncomment to      protect your pdf page with password.
      $mpdf->Output($fileName,'D');
      exit;
       ?>
```

Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.. It was the include file that was causing the problem. It is working now.